# adding GUIs to unmanaged/boost c++ applications

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

I have two console applications to which I would like to add GUIs. The console applications are standard c++ using boost and are compiled with the Microsoft c++ compiler.

I managed to add GUIs using QT which work very nicely (I created a separate QThread to do the work of the command line app and just added an interface which started it)

But is it possible to add .NET GUIs to these console apps? I tried, but got a lot of linker errors when compiling in Visual Studio...

I guess the problem is somewhat managed vs. unmanaged c++/cli code... Can someone explain the problems in adding a .net UI to a console/boost standard c++ application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compile your C++ application as a library (or DLL in Windows terms) and use this from your .NET GUI. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/usingcppdll.aspx) article could be helpful.